# Alternating current frequency

Tags: frequency, light, speed

An introductory discussion of alternating current in a primer I was taking left me thinking. We don't see a light bulb flicker because the alternating happens at 50-60 Hz. If it takes 1.28 seconds for sunlight reflected off the moon to reach earth and I had an extension cord long enough to power a light bulb on the moon would I see the bulb flicker?

Comment: The claim that we don't see the light flicker at 50-60 Hz is simply not true. Cheap LED and fluorescent tubes flicker at double that, and while only some people may not notice it at all, some people will find it very irritating.

Comment: Explain why you think the distance would make any difference in anything other than brightness.  Depending on where you live, the nearest power plant could be hundreds of miles away, or next door.  Do you think this affects how fast the generators are spinning?

Answer (score 6):

No, as that extension cord would still transport 50 Hz (or 60 Hz) AC, and your bulb would change intensity at that rate, even if it's 1.28 s in the past when you see that light.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are a few things going on.

1. Thermal time constant of the filament if it's incandescent type. The filament doesn't cool quickly enough to stop emitting light between pulses.
2. Capacitance in LED types. Generally some capacitance is added after the rectifiers in LED lamps to reduce flicker.
3. Persistance of vision. Your eyes generally don't notice flicker above, I think, 25 Hz or so. Old CRT TVs relied on this to give the impression of continuous picture display.

In any case, the fact that it takes 1.28 s for light to reach earth makes no difference any more than it matters that it takes a few nanoseconds to reach you from a source on Earth. If you're into photon theory then the stream of photons is being emitted and they will arrive at your eye at the same rate no matter where along the light path you are.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the other answers have forgotten about the significant effects of a transmission line mismatch. That mismatch will produce a very slow "on-off" lamp effect. Is this to be regarded as fluctuation in the spirit of the question? **I think so**.

> *If it takes 1.28 seconds for sunlight reflected off the moon to reach
> earth and I had an extension cord long enough to power a light bulb on
> the moon would I see the bulb flicker?*

Based on transmission line theory (and recognizing that this is an impractical and unrealistic question), you may **indeed see the lamp flicker** for some time until the line termination reflections settle. If the lamp's resistance perfectly matched the impedance of the transmission cable then it won't flicker but, any deviation from that situation will produce reflections that will take several tens of seconds to resolve. Once resolved, the lamp (albeit very dim) will flicker at 100/120 Hz just as it does on earth.

So, here's a simulation of an ideal power cable having a characteristic impedance of 25 Ω connected over a distance of 384,000 km to a 60 watt lamp (approximately 1000 Ω) and fed from a regular 50 Hz AC source (V1 below). Note the envelope of the lamps received voltage and how it changes every few seconds or so: -

[image]
[image]

For the first 40 seconds or so, the lamp would appear to flash on and off every 7.7 seconds. Then, the lamp would gradually appear to flash but with less intensity until at around 200 seconds you'd be hard-pressed to see the slow flicker without some specialized optical instrument.

> *would I see the bulb flicker?*

I think there's a good chance of seeing flickering if you can actually see the lamp at all over that distance. However, this flicker is purely due to mismatching the load at the end of a power transmission line - this actually occurs on earth in power grids. The 100 Hz/ 120 Hz flicker will be no more visible on the moon (from the earth) than it is if you were sat next to it.

And the reason is that the flicker rate of a lamp is at (say) 120 Hz when powered from 60 Hz is because each half cycle produces a small peak in light intensity: -

[image]

Picture from [this site](https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=12161). So, in the above diagram there are 12 intensity peaks in 0.1 seconds corresponding with an intensity frequency of 120 Hz (even though the AC is 60 Hz).

Answer (score 1):

> If it takes 1.28 seconds for sunlight reflected off the moon to reach earth and I had an extension cord long enough to power a light bulb on the moon would I see the bulb flicker?

No.

Answer (score 0):

> An introductory discussion of alternating current in a primer I was taking left me thinking. We don't see a light bulb flicker because the alternating happens at 50-60 Hz. If it takes 1.28 seconds for sunlight reflected off the moon to reach earth and I had an extension cord long enough to power a light bulb on the moon would I see the bulb flicker?

You wouldn't see the bulb flicker because the frequency is constant through the conductor no matter how long the wire is. The amplitude (voltage) will be less because of the attenuation of the long run. So you would see a dimly lit bulb if it has enough voltage to light it up.